# Delete TFS Project Collection - SqlException

Tags: team-foundation-server

I'm trying to delete a team project collection in TFS 2010. Unfortunately after struggling with some old instances (some that don't even have databases anymore) I get an error even when attempting to delete a brand new instance.

I go through the detatch process and get an error during the reporting section:

> [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Error] Invalid object name 'dbo.DimTeamProject'.

[image]

How can I go about deleting collections?

Below is some of the log:

```
[Info   @15:14:39.993] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] Step Data Text: 
[Info   @15:14:39.993] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] Retrieving target request context.
[Info   @15:14:39.993] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] Target request context has framework connection string: Data Source=FS-01\TFSSQL2008;Initial Catalog=Tfs_DeleteMe;Integrated Security=True.
[Info   @15:14:39.993] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z] Servicing step Copy identities to collection database passed. (ServicingOperation: Snapshot; Step group: Snapshot.TfsIdentities)
[Info   @15:14:39.993] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] Retrieving target request context.
[Info   @15:14:39.993] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] Target request context has framework connection string: Data Source=FS-01\TFSSQL2008;Initial Catalog=Tfs_DeleteMe;Integrated Security=True.
[Info   @15:14:39.993] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z] Executing servicing step Prepare Build for a detach operation. (ServicingOperation: Delete; Step group: Delete.TfsBuild)
[Info   @15:14:39.993] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] Step Performer: Build
[Info   @15:14:39.993] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] Step Type:      OnDetach
[Info   @15:14:39.993] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] Step Data Text: 
[Info   @15:14:39.993] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z] Servicing step Prepare Build for a detach operation passed. (ServicingOperation: Delete; Step group: Delete.TfsBuild)
[Info   @15:14:39.994] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z] Executing servicing step Mark Collection as Deleted in Warehouse. (ServicingOperation: Delete; Step group: Delete.TfsWarehouse)
[Info   @15:14:39.994] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] Step Performer: WarehouseCollection
[Info   @15:14:39.994] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] Step Type:      MarkCollectionDeleted
[Info   @15:14:39.994] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] Step Data Text: 
[Error  @15:14:39.994] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Error] Invalid object name 'dbo.DimTeamProject'.
[Info   @15:14:39.994] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.DimTeamProject'.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.MapException(SqlException ex, QueryExecutionState queryState)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.HandleException(SqlException ex)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.Execute(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean bindReturnValue)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseBatchedDataAccessComponent.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.CommonStructureWarehouseAdapter.MarkCollectionDeleted(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, Guid collectionId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Servicing.TFCollection.WarehouseStepPerformer.MarkCollectionDeleted(String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext, Boolean validateOnly)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.IStepPerformer.PerformStep(String servicingOperation, String stepType, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group, ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Boolean validateOnly)
[Info   @15:14:39.994] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z] Servicing step Mark Collection as Deleted in Warehouse failed. (ServicingOperation: Delete; Step group: Delete.TfsWarehouse)
[Info   @15:14:39.994] [2014-03-28 15:12:50Z][Informational] Clearing dictionary, removing all items.
[Error  @15:14:39.994] The servicing operation failed.
```

Comment: I appreciate you attempting to provide us with detailed information (logs are generally good), but dumping the *whole* log on us doesn't really encourage people to help you - it makes us go "Yeah, I'm not reading all that (at least not for free)". -- Can you do a little further investigation on your own and pare this down to *the relevant details* (errors and warnings) rather than the current *everything that ever happened to the system ever since the dawn of time* log? :)

Comment: Looks like it's failing to drop the reporting data warehouse. Have you tweaked any of the field names in your work item templates?

Comment: @voretaq7: I guess at the moment I don't know much about TFS underneath) - I imagine the only useful bit is actually the exception at the end but I don't know what it's doing and can't find any similar errors encountered by people. I'm happy to just include the exception.

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown: This particular one was a brand new TFS collection created 30 seconds before without any customization whatsoever.

Comment: @Ian Yeah the exception seems to be the important bit - unfortunately I too know very little about the inner workings of TFS (but having seen the inner workings of other products I think keeping it that way may be best for my sanity...)

Comment: @voretaq7: So true - I'm very rapdily falling out with TFS. I've had a few exceptions (even just getting latest). It really should be able to do what without issue all the time unless the DB goes down.